# Can I give human medicine to chickens?

Tags: health, chickens, medicines

My dad used to medicate our [non-livestock chickens](https://pets.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/103/are-questions-about-poultry-birds-on-topic) with human drugs by dosing their water supply.  We have medicated using ampicillin, vitamin C capsules, and sometimes multivitamins. The chickens have never reacted negatively to the medication.

According to [Can I use human medicine on dogs?](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/400/can-i-use-human-medicine-on-dogs), some human medicine is poisonous to dogs.

Does the same concern apply to chickens? Are we endangering them?