# Is my dogs spay incision infected, or is this some sort of blister?

Tags: dogs, infections, neutering

[image]

My bitch was spayed on the 24th of August, so almost 3 weeks ago. This morning I noticed what looked like a small bruise near one end of her incision. Since then it has inflated into the photo I've provided.

It seems like it's sensitive to touch, but it's not weeping or overly hot. She seems fine in herself, no more licking than usual, and still playful (maybe too playful?).

I'm concerned it's an infection coming in, and with it being a weekend the only vets are emergency only. Is this something I should worry about?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To be honest, this does look somewhat worrying, but it's not uncommon for sutures to develop these blisters (here's a [similar question with more detailed answers](https://pets.stackexchange.com/a/28887/12501)). The rest of the incision healed very well, but the dark dot near the bruising could be a spot that didn't heal properly.

In my opinion, you don't need to rush to an emergency vet, unless one of the following occurs:

- Your dog is lethargic, sleeping all the time and avoiding physical activities.
- Your dog eats or drinks much less than usual.
- The bruise turns an unusual color like dark blue, greenish, yellow or black.
- The gums of your dog turn pale.

You should keep an eye on this and documenting the progress with regular photos is a good idea. If it keeps spreading, turns a strange color (other than red) or if your dog gets a fever, go to the vet on Monday.

If your dog starts excessively licking the bruise, put the e-collar (collar of shame) back on.

If your dog gets a fever or is having pain you can give her a weight-appropriate dose of dog-appropriate pain killers or anti-inflammatory pills as a first aid measure. **Most pain killers for humans are poisonous to dogs!** Please read [this question for more details](https://pets.stackexchange.com/q/400/12501).

Comment: i agree with this answer,it is best to have this looked at by a vet.

Comment: @AndyHeard When you return from the vet, you can post a comment or even your own answer with the vet's feedback. That will help future people with the same problem. Best wishes for your dog.

Comment: So the lump since I posted has gradually grown and looked like a blood blister under the skin. It's around the size of a grape currently, and at midday today it started leaking very congealed blood. The vet has prescribed the cone of shame again, some anti inflammation medicine and asked me to keep an eye on the wound. They believe it could be a suture that the body is not so happy with, so I'm going again next week to see how it's healed / not healed. They don't seem overly worried, as it's not infected at all, and is probably something the dog can heal herself.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you so much for posting this.  My dog was spayed 4 weeks ago, 2 weeks ago she had swelling under the incision but the incision looked as though it was healing or healed perfectly, she was sleeping all day, sick I took her in and she was treated with 10 days of antibiotics and anti-inflammatory meds. She was doing great on the meds. After the 10 days, maybe day 12, no meds, she was swollen again, totally lethargic and not using one of her back legs (on and off). She had a follow up that day so I told them about what I had noticed (we don't go in with the dog due to covid regs.) 15 minutes later they brought my dog back to the car and said,"DR. said it's looking good. I protested, they insisted, I left.  The following day she wouldn't even move. I took her back again and they gave me another round of the anti-inflammatory medication and it worked like a charm, 12 hours later she was running around acting crazy! The following day, Sunday, I wake up to this...I had no idea what was going on. Thankfully it looks a lot like what your dog had and I won't worry as much because we don't go back until Thursday.  I was surprised that a reaction to the sutures took 4 weeks, also surprised that my Dr. couldn't see it or figure it out but it looks pretty common. [image]